# Django, apps list template tag in admin base.html

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates, django-apps

So I'm trying to create a template for the Django Admin. What I can't manage to show is a list(going to be a menu) with all the apps installed. Pretty much exactly the same as index.html of the django admin template. I found an article on how to recreate this list on [this link](http://smotko.si/navbar-in-django-admin/). I am not 100% that this code will work with Django 1.7 rc1 (tried also with 1.6 but still nothing) but I thought I could give it a try.

The main issue is that I can't manage how to display the template tag with the menu. I've created custom template tags in the past so I double checked the following:

- **init**.py inside the templatetags folder
- the app and the template tag both registered in settings

The error I am getting is **'custom_menu' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading djangobackend.apps.djangonicebackend.templatetags.custom_menu: cannot import name validate.....**.

Below you can find my code.

**custom_menu.py** (inside template tags directory)

```
from django.utils.text import capfirst
from django.db.models import get_models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from django.contrib.admin.validation import validate
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django import template

register = template.Library()

IGNORE_MODELS = (
    "sites",
    "sessions",
    "admin",
    "contenttypes",
)


def custom_app_list(request):
    # Get all models and add them to the context apps variable.
    user = request.user
    app_dict = {}
    admin_class = ModelAdmin
    for model in get_models():
        validate(admin_class, model)
        model_admin = admin_class(model, None)
        app_label = model._meta.app_label
        if app_label in IGNORE_MODELS:
            continue
        has_module_perms = user.has_module_perms(app_label)
        if has_module_perms:
            perms = model_admin.get_model_perms(request)
            # Check whether user has any perm for this module.
            # If so, add the module to the model_list.
            if True in perms.values():
                model_dict = {
                    'name': capfirst(model._meta.verbose_name_plural),
                    'admin_url': mark_safe('%s/%s/' % (app_label, model.__name__.lower())),
                }
                if app_label in app_dict:
                    app_dict[app_label]['models'].append(model_dict)
                else:
                    app_dict[app_label] = {
                        'name': app_label.title(),
                        'app_url': app_label + '/',
                        'has_module_perms': has_module_perms,
                        'models': [model_dict],
                    }
    app_list = app_dict.values()
    app_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
    for app in app_list:
        app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
    return {'apps': app_list}


t = get_template('templatetags/custom_menu.html')
register.inclusion_tag(t)(custom_app_list)
```

**custom_menu.html** (app/templates/templatetags/custom_menu.html)

```
<ul class="nav">
        {% for app in custom_apps %}
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {% trans app.name %}<b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for model in app.models %}
            <li><a href="/{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**also**

in the top of `templates/admin/base.html` I have `{% load custom_menu %}` and in the place that the menu should show up i got `{% custom_app_list request %}`.

Comment: Your error doesn't seem to match the code you've given. Are you sure you are using `{% load custom_menu %}` and not `{% load custom_app_list %}`? If you have changed it, make sure you have reloaded the server, and update your question with the actual error.

Comment: Yes you are right @Alasdair! I updated my code and error. I've just changed what you said and forgot to updated the error.

Comment: You might be able to get the code to work in Django 1.6 without too many changes. Apps have changed quite a lot in Django 1.7 so that will probably be trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This import is not valid, so is raising `ImportError`:

```
from django.contrib.admin.validation import validate
```

The module [`django.contrib.admin.validation`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/contrib/admin/validation.py) does not contain a function `validate`. It has a `BaseValidator` object which has a `validate` method.

It's not clear to me why you're trying to import `validate` anyway. Try removing the import, and the line where you call `validate` from your template tag.

For your second error, you need to make sure that the `request` is in the template context. The easiest way of doing this is to add the [request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Comment: Hmm did that and now I'm getting `'str' object has no attribute 'user'`. There is something wrong with `{% custom_app_list request %}`. I think the code(you can find the link in the question) is kinda old so I'm not sure what changed since then.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you! Added the request to the template context and it works now, even though it still does not show the apps but I guess I have to fix this two. Is there any way of doing this without changing anything to the settings(without adding the request)?

Comment: The template tag needs the request object so that it can check the user's permissions. You could alter all of the admin views to include `request` in the template context, but using the template context processor is much easier.

Comment: I fixed the issue and it works now so once again thank you! The thing is that I'm planing to create a package for the project and I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible so I don't want users to alter their settings (apart from adding the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`. That's the reason I would like to avoid using the template context processor.

Comment: For the reason I gave before, I don't think you can realistically avoid having to add the template context processor. When installing a Django app, it is pretty common to have to add an entry to the middleware or template context processors, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.